# C Program that takes 10 strings from user and puts them in a 2D array then proceeds to sort them according to string lengths and alphabetical order

Tags: c, arrays

I programmed a code that takes 10 names and puts them in a 2d array and then proceeds to print out the shortest and longest string. In addition it prints out the first and last string according to the alphabetical order of the first string. I have been sitting on this code for hours and can not understand why it is not properly functioning. If someone could go over the code and find out whats wrong with it that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define ROWS 10
#define COLUMNS 51
#define FIRST_LETTER_OF_STRING 0
#define END_OF_NUMBERS 64

void newfgets(char string[], int size);
void userInput(char nameArray[][COLUMNS]);
void shortestAndLongest(char nameArray[][COLUMNS]);
void firstLast(char nameArray[][COLUMNS]);

int main(void)
{
    char nameArray[ROWS][COLUMNS] = { 0 };
    userInput(nameArray);
    shortestAndLongest(nameArray);
    firstLast(nameArray);

    return 0;
}

/*Function takes 10 names from user and puts them in an array of strings
input: names array
output: none
*/
void userInput(char nameArray[][COLUMNS])
{
    int i = 0;

    printf("Enter %d names:\n", ROWS);

    for(i=0;i<ROWS;i++)
    {   
        fgets(nameArray[i], COLUMNS , stdin);
        newfgets(nameArray[i] , COLUMNS);
    }
}   

/*Function calculates the shortest and the longest string and prints them to the screen
input: string array
output: none*/

void shortestAndLongest(char nameArray[][COLUMNS])
{
    int i = 0;
    int biggestStringSize = 0;
    int biggestStringSequenceNumber = 0;//the number of the place in the array where the smallest string is stored
    int smallestStringSize = 0;
    int smallestStringSequenceNumber = 0;//the number of the place in the array where the biggest string is stored

    for(i=0;i<ROWS;i++)
    {
        if(strlen(nameArray[i]) > biggestStringSize)//is the current string longer then the longest string?
        {
            if(i == 1)//is this the second iteration?
            {
                smallestStringSize = biggestStringSize;
                smallestStringSequenceNumber = biggestStringSequenceNumber;
            }

            biggestStringSequenceNumber = i;
            biggestStringSize = strlen(nameArray[i]);

        }
        else if(strlen(nameArray[i]) < smallestStringSize)//is the current string longer then the shortest string?
        {
            smallestStringSequenceNumber = i;
            smallestStringSize = strlen(nameArray[i]);
        }   

    }   

    printf("Shortest: %s\nLongest:%s\n", nameArray[smallestStringSequenceNumber], nameArray[biggestStringSequenceNumber]);
}   

/*Function calculates the first and last letter according to alphabetical order and prints them to the screen
input: name array
output: none
*/      
void firstLast(char nameArray[][COLUMNS])
{
    int i = 0;
    int lastLetter = 0;//last letter ascii size
    int firstLetter = 0;//first letter ascii size
    int firstSeqNumber = 0;//the place in the array where the first string according to alphabetical order is stored
    int lastSeqNumber = 0;////the place in the array where the last string according to alphabetical order is stored

    for(i=0;i<ROWS;i++)
    {
        if(nameArray[i][FIRST_LETTER_OF_STRING] > lastLetter && nameArray[i][FIRST_LETTER_OF_STRING] > END_OF_NUMBERS)//second part of if makes sure numbers are ignored
        {
            printf("IF FIRST OF STRING %d END OF NUMBERS: %d\n", nameArray[i][FIRST_LETTER_OF_STRING], END_OF_NUMBERS);
            if(i==1)//is this the second iteration??
            {
                firstLetter = lastLetter;
                firstSeqNumber = lastSeqNumber;
            }   

            lastLetter = nameArray[i][FIRST_LETTER_OF_STRING];
            lastSeqNumber = i;
        }
        else if(nameArray[i][FIRST_LETTER_OF_STRING] < firstLetter && nameArray[i][FIRST_LETTER_OF_STRING] > END_OF_NUMBERS)//second part of if makes sure numbers are ignored
        {
            printf("ELSE IF FIRST OF STRING %d END OF NUMBERS: %d\n", nameArray[i][FIRST_LETTER_OF_STRING], END_OF_NUMBERS);
            firstLetter = nameArray[i][FIRST_LETTER_OF_STRING];
            firstSeqNumber = i;
        }
    }

    printf("First: %s\nLast: %s", nameArray[firstSeqNumber], nameArray[lastSeqNumber]);
}   






/*Function solves the problelm fgets has*/
void newfgets(char string[], int size)
{
    int i = 0;
    int flag = 0;

    for(i=0;i<size && flag == 0;i++)
    {
        if(string[i] == '\n')
        {
            string[i] = 0;
            flag++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It would help if you gave more precise details of your problem. All you have really told us is "it doesn't work" which isn't very helpful. What is the input, expected result and actual result? What debugging did you do and what did you find? Please review [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same results.  the posted code causes the compiler to output 5 warnings.  For each warning, the compiler generates some 'work around'.  That does not mean the 'work around' is what you intended.

Comment: regarding: `void newfgets(char string[], int size)`  This is a bad idea.  Rather use: `if( fgets( buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin ) )`  If the code continues into the body of the `if`, then `fgets` was successful, then to remove the trailing newline: `buffer[ strcspn( buffer, "\n" ) ] = '\0';`

Comment: regarding: `if(i == 1)`  This is skipping the first string checking.  so the logic needs some re-design

Comment: when looking for the shortest the field should be initialized to a very large number, like `INT_MIN`.   When looking for the longest the field should be initialized to a vary small number like: `INT_MAX`